# Software to send audio via usb in Windows

Tags: windows, audio, usb

I have a USB-RCA cable. I want to use it to send an audio signal from my Windows 7 computer to an older audio component.

Windows does not recognize a device as present; I think this means that this component isn't pnp-enabled, which is true.

I have checked, and the Windows "generic USB audio" driver is present. I have no reason to think there is anything wrong with it.

I have AVIO4ALL, but can't figure out how to make it do what I want.

The USB port works fine.

I suspect that the best solution is to get a piece of software that will create a virtual audio device, on the USB port, and then tell Windows to use that device.

Can you recommend such a piece of software?